# How to get Information about indexes of system views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How I can get information about indexes of system views.

I write this query and look at execution plan.I saw it used Index scan rather Index seek.Any one know why?

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) TableName, st.row_count
 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
 WHERE index_id < 2 AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)='Mytbl'
```

[image]

Comment: why do you care? system views are system views. It's not like you need to optimise them!

Comment: Yes.I want it for my personal information.

Comment: +1 I think it is perfectly reasonable to want to replace the scan with a seek.

Comment: I bet you are getting the scan because there are just not that many rows, so it is more efficient to just scan them.

Comment: @RacerX - You lose your bet. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select i.name  as idx_name,
       i.type_desc,
       i.is_unique,
       ac.name as col_name,
       c.key_ordinal,
       c.is_descending_key,
       c.is_included_column
from   sys.indexes i
       join sys.all_objects a
         on a.object_id = i.object_id
       join sys.index_columns c
         on c.object_id = i.object_id
            and c.index_id = i.index_id
       join sys.all_columns ac
         on ac.object_id = i.object_id
            and c.column_id = ac.column_id
where  a.name = 'sysidxstats'
```

Returns

```
idx_name          type_desc       is_unique col_name    key_ordinal is_descending_key is_included_column
----------------- --------------- --------- ----------- ----------- ----------------- ------------------
clst              CLUSTERED       1         id          1           0                 0
clst              CLUSTERED       1         indid       2           0                 0
nc                NONCLUSTERED    1         name        1           0                 0
nc                NONCLUSTERED    1         id          2           0                 0
```

Use

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) TableName,
       st.row_count
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE  index_id < 2
       AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('Mytbl')
```

To get an index seek.

[image: PLAN WITH SEEK]

`WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id)='Mytbl'` is not a seekable predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/24/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-diffefence-and-usage-a-simple-note/ it doesn't talk about how to get index info from system views but it does explain why reasons why an Index Scan may be used over an Index Seek.